# How to pass callback function definitions as parameters while evaluating a JavaScript using eval()?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have in a json object which stores a JavaScript say

```
    var jsonObj = {
      "js": "var x=1;\n   callback(x);"
    }
```

Now to execute this JavaScript, I need to provide an implementation for callback. Lets say our callback just prints the value x.

How then am I supposed to make the call using jsonObj.js such that the given javascript executes and prints the value of x (callback prints the value).

I tried the eval function but either my syntax was wrong or perhaps eval is not used here at all.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Note: If it helps, I am actually writing a firefox plugin using gwt. This peace of code is written as a native JavaScript function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to pass in the `callback`, you'd use the `Function` constructor instead of `eval`, and define the parameters.

```
var jsonObj = {
  "js": "var x=1;\n   callback(x);"
};

var f = Function('callback', jsonObj.js);
```

Then you can pass the function argument:

```
f(function(n) { alert(n); }); // 1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWCVD/

---

The `Function` constructor is designed such that the last argument you pass it is the body of the function, and all the preceding arguments are the parameters to the function.

So if you want to add additional parameters, you'd just give them to the `Function` constructor.

```
var jsonObj = {
  "js": "var x=y + 1;\n   callback(x);"
};

var f = Function('y', 'callback', jsonObj.js);
```

Then pass the arguments:

```
//  v-"y"
//  v
  f(2, function(n) { alert(n); }); // 3
//         ^
//         ^-"callback"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWCVD/16

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. Also, thanks for mentioning jsfiddle. I was looking for a site like this :)

Comment: And how do we pass some parameter to the above mentioned javascript? eg. say js stores "var x=y+1;\n   callback(x);" and I want to provide the value of y in the definition, what changes must be made while calling? I tried adding a parameter but didn't work.

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal: The `Function` constructor is designed so that the last argument you give it is the body of the function, and all preceding arguments are the parameters. This means if we want to add a `y` parameter to the function, we would do this: `var f = Function('y', 'callback', jsonObj.js);` Now we're creating a function with the parameters `y` and `callback`. So we can call the resulting function like `f(2, function(n) { alert(n); });`. I'll update my answer.